# Scala IDE failing to be installed

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, ide

I have checked here but I cannot find anybody with the same kind of issue.

I am trying to install the 4.7.0 version of the Scala IDE based on Eclipse available at http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html for Windows 10. While the download seems to be working fine, once I unzip the file I get a pop-up message that says "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

[image: Screenshot of the latter message is here]

The configuration file eclipse.ini (still within the downloaded scala IDE) is:

```
*-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m*
```

I have tried to increase the heap memory size to 512 and 1024 MB or using winzip instead of winrar for installing the program (apparently, there was some issue with WinRAR according to some people) but to no avail. Do you have any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to install such an old software? It seems from the release notes that it was released in early 2018 and only supports Scala 2.12 and Java 1.8. The current stable versions of Scala are 2.13 and 3.2, of Java it is Java 17.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If that code only supports Java 8 it may not work with Java 9 or later.

Comment: The **ScalaIDE** for **Eclipse** was already deprecated like 5 years ago when I started to learn the language, and it was officially closed a couple of years ago. - Pick either **IntelliJ** or **metals** _(which can be used with newer versions of **Eclipse**, although I believe it also has some issues in that platform)_ - I personally are very happy with **vscode** + **metals** + **sbt** + **WSL**

Comment: Is there literally an asterisk at the end of that last line on the .ini file? That looks like a mistake if so. And are you on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: You can try opening CMD and running Eclipse from it, to get some logs, which could potentially help figure out the cause... but unless you have some good reasons to use Scala IDE use something else. It's an abandonware, and - contrary to what some people I've met been saying - IntelliJ CE is mostly OSS (Apache - see https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community), same with Scala plugin (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala). Metals is obviously an OSS LSP, where you can pick among a plethora of editors that support it. Unless you love Eclipse or use some ancient Scala, skip Scala IDE.